# Regular expressions help in javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex

i am not sure as to why this code is not working, on the website where i found the code it say it should print any letter between capital a to z. i tried the same thing with a number, to print numbers between 0-9 but it does not work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <script>
      var string = "THIS IS AN EXAMPLE";
      var str = /[A-Z]/;

      document.write(string.match(str));
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Well, you haven't posted your code; but if you were testing the regex `/[0-9]/` on the string `"THIS IS AN EXAMPLE"`, then your problem is that `"THIS IS AN EXAMPLE"` doesn't contain any digits!

Comment: If your code is correct. Check the browser compatibility. IE has some problems with regular expressions.

Comment: Keep this tool in your favourites, I find it really handy http://regexpal.com/

Comment: It is working, but it is only printing the first character, since String.match returns an array of matches: [mdn - String.match](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FString%2Fmatch)

Comment: i am not testing /[0-9]/ on a string but why does the code above not work. i am testing this using the w3c editor.

Comment: `str.exec(string)` try this.

Comment: @mr-green what does exec do?

Comment: REGEX.exec(STRING);  is simply going to return the first result or null if there is no match  http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_regexp_exec.asp

Comment: why does this not work http://jsfiddle.net/K55NL/3/

Comment: regex evaluates characters and strings specifically; and "10" does not qualify as a character - to accomplish that you want to do this: http://jsfiddle.net/K55NL/4/    characters from 0-9

Answer (score 3):

EDIT:

updated after clarified question

```
 <script>

 var string = "1 2 3 4 8 9 11 15 18 293";
 var str = /[0-9]*/g;

 var arr = string.match(str);

 var length = arr.length;

 for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
     if ( parseInt(arr[i]) <= 9 && parseInt(arr[i]) >= 1){
         document.write(arr[i] + " ");
     }
 }

 </script>
```

[new fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/K55NL/5/)

---

what you are telling javascript to do is only print the first character in the array of results matching your regex.  you also have not accounted for the "space" character in  your regular expression

to the best of my understanding this is what you are trying to accomplish - but if this is incorrect please clarify what results you are trying to achieve.

***[take a look at this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/K55NL/)***

```
 <script>

 var string = "THIS IS AN EXAMPLE";
 var str = /[A-Z ]*/;

 document.write(string.match(str));

 </script>
```

note how ive used `/[A-Z ]*/`

including the space character in the matching set as well as an asterisk to denote matching any number of these characters.  if you are attempting to only match the first word and stop at a space simply remove it.

in either case

[here is a great article from the mozilla developer network explaining regex in all of its glory - pertaining specifically to its use with javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#Advanced_Searching_With_Flags)

in case you decide you would like to take a gander at the 'manual'

Comment: why not /[A-Z]/g if he wants to match the letters?

Comment: @joe, why does this not work when i change the " THIS IS AN EXAMPLE" TO 1234565" and then chnage a-z to 0-9?

Comment: Yalda - see my comment above,  Harry - /[A-Z]/g would work great if that is the goal here, to match only the capital alphabet characters and eliminate the spaces.  i interpreted the question another way, still unsure of the exact desire results.

Comment: ok i will tell you what i want, i want to have a set of numbers lets say from 1 to 15, and then print the numbers in the rnage of 1-9;

Comment: in that case the first thing that comes to mind would be to grab all of the numbers with a regex match / placing them in an array.  then you can traverse the array with a loop and print those numbers after evaluating them with mathematical comparisons

Comment: see the new fiddle and the update - also please update your question - thanks! hope that helps

Comment: +1 @Joe 10-4 just wanted to throw that out there without trying to hijack your answer ;-)